# Array 2D to 1D conversion and confusion

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am confused to convert a 2D array into 1D array.
I want to write a neighboring 8 elements for "a11" (which is at (1,1)) in the form of width ,rows and cols format without using for loop.

```
       |<--Width--->|
            cols
        ____________
       | a00 a01 a02 
  rows | a10 a11 a12 
       | a20 a21 a22
```

I tried in this way :

```
a00 = pSrc[(cols-1)+ (rows - 1)*width];                                           
a02 = pSrc[(cols-1)+ (rows  + 1)*width];                                           
a10 = pSrc[cols+ (rows -1)*width];                                                 
a12 = pSrc[cols+ (rows +1)*width];                                                 
a20 = pSrc[(cols+1)+ (rows  - 1)*width];                                           
a22 = pSrc[(cols+1)+ (rows  + 1)*width];                                           
a01 = pSrc[(cols-1)+ (rows )*width];                                               
a21 = pSrc[(cols+1)+ (rows )*width];
```

But I think I did some mistake .Can any one help me in that .

Comment: For your information `a[i][j] = *(*(a+ i) + j)`.

Comment: I don't want to use for loop as I am writing the code in OpenCL .I am replacing for loop with kernel code .Can you give your answer in above format that I have mentioned

Comment: How is `pSrc` defined?  Is `cols` set to `1` (and is `rows` set to `1`) for your example case?

Comment: Yes..rows and cols set to 1 ..and psrc is global uchar *pSrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear how `pSrc` is defined since you don't show its definition.  However, your code is consistent with it being declared as a 1D array:

```
int pSrc[9];   // Or a larger dimension
```

Your code can sensibly be written so it is more uniformly laid out:

```
a00 = pSrc[(cols-1) + (rows-1)*width];
a01 = pSrc[(cols-1) + (rows+0)*width];
a02 = pSrc[(cols-1) + (rows+1)*width];
a10 = pSrc[(cols+0) + (rows-1)*width];
a12 = pSrc[(cols+0) + (rows+1)*width];
a20 = pSrc[(cols+1) + (rows-1)*width];
a21 = pSrc[(cols+1) + (rows+0)*width];
a22 = pSrc[(cols+1) + (rows+1)*width];
```

The `+0` will be ignored by even the most simple-minded compiler, almost certainly without even turning the optimizer on, but it makes the code much easier to read.  I also resequenced the entries so the row above are listed first, then the row in the middle, and then the bottom row.  Again, it makes it easier to see the patterns.

It is then clear that you are using 'rows' and 'cols' backwards.  You actually need:

```
a00 = pSrc[(cols-1) + (rows-1)*width];
a01 = pSrc[(cols+0) + (rows-1)*width];
a02 = pSrc[(cols+1) + (rows-1)*width];
a10 = pSrc[(cols-1) + (rows+0)*width];
a12 = pSrc[(cols+1) + (rows+0)*width];
a20 = pSrc[(cols-1) + (rows+1)*width];
a21 = pSrc[(cols+0) + (rows+1)*width];
a22 = pSrc[(cols+1) + (rows+1)*width];
```